# How to stop a list variable set as another list variable from affecting the other list?

Tags: python, list

I've been playing around with lists and I've been having trouble with code like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
b.append(5)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Why is b.append appending to list a as well? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Use `b = a.copy()`

Comment: There is no other list, **they are the same list**.